# How to include 'mysql_secure_installation' using CloudFormation template in AWS

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

What is the best way to include the steps for `mysql_secure_installation` in a template using CloudFormation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Deploying Applications on Amazon EC2 with AWS CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html). Specifically the `UserData` property and `Metadata` properties.

You can use either one of those to run the `mysql_secure_installation` command when the instance launches.